# Regrex to exclude double space in Textfields input

Tags: reactjs, regex

I a trying to restrict textfield from taking double space but it should take single space . Here is my expression which allows space to enter

```
^[a-z]{1}[a-zA-Z- ]
```

If anyone knows how to restrict multiple space please help me.

Comment: You can repeat the space `^[a-z][a-z]*(?: [a-zA-Z-]+)*$` or if you want to repeat the space or hyphen but not at the end `^[a-z][a-z]*(?:[ -][a-zA-Z]+)*$` https://regex101.com/r/CehD8y/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either repeat the character class with hyphen and optionally repeat the same preceded by a space

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(?: [a-zA-Z-]+)* ?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[a-zA-Z]+` Match 1+ chars in the range a-z A-Z
- `(?: [a-zA-Z-]+)*` Optionally repeat a space and chars a-z A-Z or `-`
- `?` Match an optional space
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GUiM9o/1)

Comment: Thnaks for your answer . it is works partially ,  I want  fist character should be letter A-Z , from second character should not allow  double space   , this expression not matches a sting  of abc and  space  like this "abc "

Comment: Except double space and numbers  it should match  string like "ab c" , "AbC " , "a B c"

Comment: @Kishor Like this? `^[a-zA-Z]+(?: [a-zA-Z-]+)* ?$` https://regex101.com/r/GUiM9o/1

Comment: yes it is working for me . thanks , you saved me. But can you explain me this how it is working . i did not  understand yours non matching pattern,  and this regrex is unsafe itseems.
 https://openbase.com/js/safe-regex/documentation

Comment: @Kishor I have updated the answer with the last pattern.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233238/discussion-between-kishor-and-the-fourth-bird).